# How to assgin element value according to its index in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

```
for i in range shape(L)[0]:
    L[i,:,:,:,0] = i
for j in range shape(L)[2]:
    L[:,:,j,:,1] = j
```

For example, what if I want to implement the piece of code above:

(actually, I tend to use `tf.gather` therefore I need to create a index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the type of L? if it's a tensor you will have to pass through a tf.py_func function (i think it's the best option since it will allow you to treat your tensor object as a numpy.array and from then it's trivial) cf :

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/py_func

else it seems complicated cf :

[is their a scatter_update() for placeholder in tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44803314/is-their-a-scatter-update-for-placeholder-in-tensorflow)

Comment: Thank you for answer my first question . the answer solved my problem but I am not sure whether the py_func will decrease the efficiency of the model if the tensor has a huge shape . Thank you

Comment: your welcome =), for the complexity of py_func i don't know.
If you mean the accuracy of the model you have to know that py_func doesn't update the gradient (very sadely...) or I missed it 
So if you are doing an op on your neural net it might cost you accuracy.